Why can we not experimentally evaluate the expectation value of the CHSH operator after simplifying its expression to check entanglement?
We have the observable corresponding to the CHSH inequality given by,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{\hat{S}} &= \hat{Z}_1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (-\hat{Z}_2 - \hat{X}_2)\right) + \hat{X}_1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (-\hat{Z}_2 - \hat{X}_2)\right) + \hat{X}_1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\hat{Z}_2 - \hat{X}_2)\right) - \hat{Z}_1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\hat{Z}_2 - \hat{X}_2)\right) \\
\end{align}
If we simply the expression of the operator $\mathcal{\hat{S}}$, we get,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{\hat{S}} &= -\sqrt{2}\left( \hat{Z}_1\hat{Z}_2 \ + \hat{X}_1\hat{X}_2  \right) 
\end{align}
What is the issue with evaluating the expectation value of the simplified operator for $\mathcal{\hat{S}}$ parameter experimentally instead of the complete operator? (If one just wants to check whether the state is entangled or not.) The number of measurements required would be less for this case.

I agree that your simplified observable works to demonstrate entanglement. But that’s not the purpose of CHSH. Its objective is to show Local Realism is untenable. Entanglement alone does not accomplish that, at least not in basic Bell tests.

@DrChinese So this implies that this operator can serve as an entanglement witness? Can you provide some resource where they have discussed about this?

@HypnoticZebra Discussed about what?

@NorbertSchuch About whether the measurements of the expectation value of the reduced operator is indicative of entanglement or not.

Bell violation implies entanglement (because any separable state admits an LHV description) so this is obvious. Do you want a reference why separable implies LHV?

... and that the "reduced" and the "original" operator are the same you showed.

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504079

@NorbertSchuch So what I get is that, the complete set of measurements are required to verify(with no loopholes) whether the entangled states admit a LHVM model or not (As we know they do not). And the "reduced" operator works as an entanglement witness just the same way the "original" one. So in an experimental scenario we can measure only $\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z$ to determine whether the states are entangled. PS: I am yet to go over the link you have sent. Will get back after I have read it.
